# Looping over groups in SAS

Tags: loops, sas

I have 55 weeks of sales data of a certain item. I created two SAS datasets from the original data. The first dataset has the date and the sum of quantity sold in each date. Therefore, I have 385 observations (55 x 7). The second table has detailed transaction data. Specifically, for each date, I have the time between transactions, which is the time between the arrival of one customer and the next one who purchased that item (I call it the interarrival times). What I need to do next is as follows:

1. For the first table (daily sales) I need to take the sales data for
   each week, fit a number of distributions to find the parameters of
   each one, and record those parameters in a separate table. Note that
   each week has eaxctly 7 observations
2. For the second table (interarrival times) I also need to fit a
   number of distributions to find the parameters of each one, and
   record those parameters in the same table above, but here, I don’t
   have an exact number of observations in each week

Note: I already labeled the week number for the observations in each of the two datasets and I wrote the code that fits the distributions to the data. The only area in which I am struggling is how to tell SAS to take the data for one week, do the calculations, fit the distributions, and then move to the next week (i.e. group the data by week and perform multiple statements on each group).

I tried so many methods and none of them worked including nested loops. I know how to get the weekly sales using other methods and procedures such as PROC SQL, but I am not sure whether I can fit distributions with PROC SQL.

I am using proc nlp to estimate the parameters of each distribution using the maximum likelihood method. For example, if I need to estimate Mu and Sigma for the normal distribution, I am using the following code:

```
proc nlp data= temp vardef=n covariance=h outest=parms;
  title "Normal";
  max loglik;
  parms mu=0, sigma=1;
  bounds sigma > 1e-12;
  loglik=-log(sigma*(2*constant('PI'))**.5) - 0.5*((x-mu)/sigma)**2;
run;
```

This method will find Mu and Sigma that most likely produced the data.

Comment: You have the show the code on how to fit the distributions and preferably what you've tried. SO is not a code writing services.  The solution highly depends on how you fit a distribution, either BY group processing or a macro.

Comment: Although it's not your question here, fitting a distribution to 7 data points seems questionable.

Comment: I am not asking for someone to write the code for me. I am asking for guidance on SAS logic to loop over groups. I know how to write similar code using other programming languages but it seems that SAS does things differently. Also, I've done the distribution fitting on all the data using SAS, so I don't need any help with this part. Please note that the 7 data points is just a tiny part of huge research.

Comment: Repeating my last sentence: The solution highly depends on how you fit a distribution, and will either be BY group processing or a macro. In general here's how SAS Group processing works. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001283274.htm

Comment: You may wish to explore the possibilities of `proc severity` if you have access to SAS/ETS. If not and you are considering only a few common distributions then you should check out `proc univariate` which create parameter estimates with the `histogram` statement (available via ODS tables). Both of these procedures support the `by` statement to by group processing as Reeza suggests.

Comment: In general, I prefer to use proc sql to develop my data, and I think I may try to use it here with a macro and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried proc sql with a macro and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

For others wishing to use SAS's internal grouping the `nlm` code would become:

```
/* Ensure that the data is sorted to allow group processing */
proc sort data = temp;
    by week;
run;
proc nlp data = temp vardef = n covariance = h outest = parms;
    /* Produce separate output for each week */
    by week;
    title "Normal";
    max loglik;
    parms mu = 0, sigma = 1;
    bounds sigma > 1e-12;
    loglik = -log(sigma * (2 * constant('PI'))**.5) - 0.5 * ((x - mu) / sigma)**2;
run;
```

And here is a method using `proc univariate`:

```
/* Suppress printed output (remove to see all the details) */
ods select none;
proc univariate data = temp;
    /* Produce separate output for each week */
    by week;
    histogram x / 
        /* Request fitting to normal distribution */
        normal
        /* You can select other distributions too */
        lognormal; 
    /* Put the fitted parameters in a dataset */
    ods output ParameterEstimates = parms;
    /* Put the fit statistics in a dataset */
    ods output GoodnessOfFit = quality;
run;
/* Restore printing output */
ods select all;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used

```
%macro weekly;
%do i=1 %to 55; 
    proc sql;
    create table temp as 
    select location, UPC, date, x, week
    from weeks
    where week = &i;
    quit;
/* I have here the rest of the code where I do my calculations and I fit the distributions to the data of each week */
%end;
%mend;
%weekly;
```

I knew that proc sql would work initially but I was wondering whether there may be a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: It's likely whatever your next 'step' is could accomplish this without creating a temp table. i.e. use SET WEEK(WHERE=(week=&i));

Comment: No need to apply a where clause or use a macro at all.  Just apply all your calculations at the group level in a single pass.  Cleaner, more maintainable, and faster code (in this case, 55x faster).